# What is the format of GHC hp profile?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a program that exhausts memory. If I were to trust `hp2pretty`, this program barely uses 1% of the heap at peak. So, I'd like to verify the contents of "suspect" `.hp` lines like:

```
(39987)listDirectoryCerts.getDirContents/listDirector...    179632
```

How else can I determine what is consuming all my heap?

Comment: What profiling options are you using and how quickly does the program exhaust memory - is it a slow, steady increase, or a sudden spike? I think I had hit that when the memory is pinned it might not register, and if the sample frequency is too low it may not "catch" the usage. I would try `-h` options to see if that shows anything different, and maybe `-i` to adjust the frequency.

Comment: Actually, this was an infinite loop. I'm curious as to why I did not see some obvious hint in the profile data. During investigation I found no information about profile output an hence this question.

Comment: You mean a hint of an infinite loop in the memory profiling data? If it was *allocating* I would expect some indication of the usage continuously growing, and that would go back to my first comment.