# Does -XStrict do anything in GHC?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I thought `-XStrict` [was supposed turn GHC into a Strict Haskell](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/commit/46a03fbec6a02761db079d1746532565f34c340f), so I tried the infinite Fibonacci sequence test

```
my_zipWith f  x [] = []
my_zipWith f []  y = []
my_zipWith f (x:xt) (y:yt) = f x y : my_zipWith f xt yt

test_fibs n = 
    let fibs = 0 : 1 : my_zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs) in
    take n fibs

main = do
        putStr $ show $ test_fibs 15
```

to see if it would blow up in memory, but it doesn't:

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.0.2

$ ghc -XStrict fibs.hs && ./fibs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( fibs.hs, fibs.o )
Linking fibs ...
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Strict` roughly adds a strictness annotation `!` everywhere it can be added to _in your file_. Libraries compiled without that flag are unaffected. Here you use the standard list type `[a]` which remains non-strict. If you defined your own list type (and associated `zipWith`, `tail`, etc.) I guess you will obtain the behavior you expect (?).

Comment: @chi I understood that from the answer. I'm just curious if it's possible to make `:`, `++`, `zipWith` and other List functions strict.

Comment: @MaxB: No, `[]` is defined as lazy. If you want strict versions of base types, there’s [`Data.Strict.List.List`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict-base-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Strict-List.html) from `strict-base` (although `vector` is preferable) and the [`strict`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict) package for some others. These have instances of standard classes like `Foldable`. `zipWith` isn’t overloaded in `base` but there’s [`Zip`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/keys-3.12.3/docs/Data-Key.html#t:Zip) in `keys` (split out from the older `category-extras`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Strict` pragma certainly let GHC evaluate everything strictly, but into only [Weak Head Normal Form](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/09/all-about-strictness/). For example:

```
(a, b) = (error "a", error "b")
```

If above code exists under `Strict` pragma, any error arises. Let's see your code:

```
test_fibs n = 
    let fibs = 0 : 1 : my_zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs) in
    take n fibs
```

`fibs` called recursively but in list cons, so now whole list is WHNF. That is reason why your code didn't stack.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872898/what-is-weak-head-normal-form) will help you also. Enjoy recursion and laziness!

**Add:**

An easy way, to use [deepseq](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq):

```
{-# LANGUAGE Strict #-}
import Control.DeepSeq

my_zipWith f  x [] = []
my_zipWith f []  y = []
my_zipWith f (x:xt) (y:yt) = force $ f x y : my_zipWith f xt yt

test_fibs :: Int -> [Int]
test_fibs n = 
    let fibs = 0 : 1 : my_zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs) in
    force $ take n fibs

main = do
        putStr $ show $ test_fibs 15
```

`force` defined as `` force x = x `deepSeq` x ``, `deepSeq` evaluate an expression deeply literally to NF (Normal Form). This conversion is achieved with `GHC.Generics`. If convert manually, just have to evaluate inside of data, so can rewrite following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Strict #-}

my_zipWith f  x [] = []
my_zipWith f []  y = []
my_zipWith f (x:xt) (y:yt) = f x y : go
    where
        go = my_zipWith f xt yt

test_fibs n = 
    let
        fib2 = my_zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
        fibs = 0 : 1 : fib2
    in
        take n fibs

main = do
        putStr $ show $ test_fibs 15
```

But they can't stack actually. Because [GHC can detect infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47127758/detect-infinite-loops-in-a-ghc-program), but it's another story.

Comment: So is there any way to use strict lists?